# MYSQL SELECT with COUNT, FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY skipping first row returned

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query as follows, I get the response and for some reason the while loop never catches the first group of status returned.  If MySQL returned status `I,S,N` it will only process the `S` and `N`.  If it returns `S,N` it will only process `N`.

```
$sql = "SELECT    COUNT(*) as cnt, status
        FROM      itemInterest
        GROUP BY  status
        ORDER BY  STATUS";

echo $sql;
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    echo $row['status'];
    if($row['status'] == "N") {
        $noResponse = $row['cnt'];
    }
    if($row['status'] == "S") {     
        $saved = $row['cnt'];
    }
    if($row['status'] == "I") {
        $interested = $row['cnt'];
    }
    if($row['status'] == "X") {    
        $noThanks = $row['cnt'];
    }
}
```

Comment: please add sample data.

Comment: row data are case-sensitive `I` is not the same as `i`. If they are lowercase, then that is a possible reason why it's failing. Plus, column names may also be case-sensitive. You also have 2 sets of brackets `$rs = mysql_query(($sql));` remove a set `$rs = mysql_query($sql);` and add `or die(mysql_error())`

Comment: ah yes, I removed the first $rs = mysql_query($sql) and it worked!  I hate stupid mistakes!!! thanks a million!

Comment: mysql is depricated. Use mysqli instead!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 sets of brackets `$rs = mysql_query(($sql));` remove a set `$rs = mysql_query($sql);`

Add `mysql_query() or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` also to check for errors.

You are using a deprecated MySQL library which will be removed from future PHP releases.

Consider using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).